# MongoDB - How to remove field from element in nested array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following structure for my document:

```
{
    "Name": "Test",
    "FieldsCollection": [{
        "GroupName": "Group",
        "Fields": [{
            "FieldName": "ABC",
            "Fields": {
                "item1": "value1",
                "item2": "value2"
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

and I need to change it to be as follows:

```
{
    "Name": "Test",
    "FieldsCollection": [{
        "GroupName": "Group",
        "Fields": [{
            "FieldName": "ABC",
            "item1": "value1",
            "item2": "value2"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Assuming that the values for `"item1": "value1","item2": "value2"` are constant for all the documents in my collection, I thought I could just remove `"FieldsCollection.Fields.Fields"` and add `"item1": "value1","item2": "value2"`

I tried the following query:

```
db.getCollection('Devices').update(
    {"FieldsCollection.Fields.FieldName":"ABC"},
    {$unset: {"FieldsCollection.Fields.Fields":1}},
    {multi:true}
)
```

But it didn't work.

What query can I use to perform this change?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html#nested-arrays

Comment: Your fields.fields is an object and not array ?

Comment: @AlexBlex, Does it mean it is not possible? I provided the query I used, can you help adjust it?

Comment: Your query for removing is not correct

Comment: @PrajvalM, If it was I wouldn't be asking this question... Do you know why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use positional [`$[all]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) (first level) & positional [`[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html) (second level) in 3.6

Something like

```
db.getCollection('Devices').update(
    {"FieldsCollection.Fields.FieldName":"ABC"},
    {$unset: {"FieldsCollection.$[].Fields.$[f].Fields":1}, 
     $set:{"FieldsCollection.$[].Fields.$[f].item1":"value1",
           "FieldsCollection.$[].Fields.$[f].item2":"value2"}
    },  
    {arrayFilters: [{ "f.FieldName":"ABC"} ],multi:true }
)
```

Comment: This gives the following error: `Failed to execute script.

Error: Fourth argument must be empty when specifying upsert and multi with an object. :
DBCollection.prototype._parseUpdate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:522:1
DBCollection.prototype.update@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:552:18
@(shell):1:1`

Comment: `No array filter found for identifier 'f' in path 'FieldsCollection.$[].Fields.$[f].Fields'`

Comment: Are you including the arrayFilters attribute in your query ? This works for me in mongo shell 3.6.

Comment: Could it be because I'm using RoboMongo?

Comment: @LiranFriedman Yes, it doesn't work in robomongo. It works in the mongo shell, but it doesn't give you expected result. It removes `Fields` with all nested properties. It doesn't  preserve `"item1": "value1"` and `"item2": "value2"`.

Comment: @LiranFriedman, nope, $set requires constant values from the query, not values from the document. see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11345. $set is not going to work unless nested properties are known and are the same in all documents.

Comment: I know, and I also stated those exact words in my question.
The values are indeed constant for all the documents, so $set will be fine in this case.

Comment: Sorry missed the second part of the question. You are right. $set should work. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for helping out :-)

Answer (score 1):

As your Fields.Fields is a object it is quite difficult.

This would be the query for removing :

```
db.getCollection('Devices').update(
    {Name : "test", "FieldsCollection.Fields.FieldName":"ABC"},
    {$unset: {"FieldsCollection.Fields.$.Fields":1}},
    {multi:true}
)
```